# JDK Specification Error

Tags: installation, weblogic

I'm trying to install WebLogic Server on RedHat Linux 5, and  I installed JDK 1.6 32bit through RPM. When I try to install weblogic it is throwing the following error:

"the required jdk for this installation is version 1.6.0. the jdk you are currently running with is version 1.4.2".

And even if I check java -version it is still showing as JDK 1.4 version, not sure what is the problem. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do:

```
which java
```

What path is it pointing to? My guess is /usr/bin/java. You need to set your path to include your new java installation like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/<your version of java>
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```